# Linking CSS File on a HTML Document In Same Directory On my Hard Disk

Tags: html, css

I am using Windows 7 trying to create an offline HTML page that should link to a separate CSS file located in same directory. I tried to use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css"  />
```

but no luck.

And I also want to import another CSS file named styles2.css within style.css. Didn't check yet but putting `@import "style2.css";` on style.css may be not work as well. I can use absolute links like `C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\Desktop\offline\style.css` but it won't work if I move the folder anywhere else from Desktop. Is there any code that calls/adds the link of the folder?

Comment: Try removing the forward slash if it is in the same directory.

Comment: That is also working @FirstLegion. What if css's are in subfolder or page.html are in subfolder?

Comment: If the css is in another directory then you can do <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foldername/styles.css" /> If the html is in a subdirector then do this <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles.css"  />

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css"  />` instead. Note: `href="/styles.css"` changed to `href="./styles.css"`, which is current directory of your script.

Comment: @Sahriar: It is common standard practice for your /public_html folder to be the default folder from where your webserver serves contents from.    The notation `./`  means `this directory` (i.e. current directory); while `/` means the root directory (in this case, the directory where `/public_html` resides).    So on your production server, when you want to refer a file from the same folder you are running a script, you can use the `./filename` notation. This is basically "Relative Path Referencing".    Read this nice wikipedia article on Path: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)

Answer (score 11):

While the accepted answer is not wrong it's over-complicate things.

If your file is https://www.google.com/b/bananacream/bananas/index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
```

Will try to get https://www.google.com/style.css as the last / tells the file is located in the "root" folder.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Will try to get https://www.google.com/b/bananacream/bananas/style.css as nothing indicate what folder the file is located in it will use the same folder as the requesting file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
```

Will try to get https://www.google.com/b/bananacream/bananas/style.css as ./ tell that the file is located in the same folder as the requesting file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
```

Will try to get https://www.google.com/b/bananacream/style.css as ../ tell that the file is located in the previous folder as the requesting file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../style.css">
```

Will try to get https://www.google.com/b/style.css as ../../ tell that the file is located in the folder two steps before as the requesting file.

Answer (score 6):

A general complete answer:

to address through existing folder, use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
```

to address through parent folder, use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
```

to address through the internet( CDN ) use:

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3./css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
  >
```

to address through your hard drive use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='file:///C:/mystyles.css'>
```

Answer (score 3):

try this one, it worked for me.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
```

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers. If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help.